# Dplyr programming pattern for mutate

Tags: r, nse

I have been using a standard pattern when using dplyr mutate inside functions. Here is a toy example(only to prove a point):

```
myFunction = function(colname) {
    dots <- setNames(list(lazyeval::interp(~ifelse(x>25, x*10, x/10), x = quote(colname))), "my_new_col")
    mutate_(mtcars, .dots = dots)
}
```

I have made this into a function to not type it out every time. But this is rather verbose and I am not sure if there is a simpler way to parameterize calls to mutate_. Suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: This is just a toy example. I am trying to parameterize calls to dplyr's mutate and filter by putting them inside a function.

Comment: "made it into a function to not type it out every time". Type what out exactly? Perhaps you could provide an example where you _don't_ put it into a function. Your toy example doesn't have `filter` in it either

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your function is trying to create a new column based on an existing column. Here is the function using the `tidyeval` approach. See [Programming with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184566/dplyr-programming-pattern-for-mutate) for details.

```
myFunction = function(df, col, new_col) {
    col <- enquo(col)
    new_col <- quo_name(enquo(new_col))

    df %>% 
        mutate(!!new_col := ifelse((!!col) > 25, (!!col) * 10, (!!col) / 10))
}

myFunction(mtcars, mpg, mpg_based_new_col)
```